# How to write into BitSet from byteArray? (we need java 1.7)

Tags: java, bitset

How to write into BitSet from byteArray?

Say if I have a `byte[] bytearray` how to input this to a BitSet?

Comment: `BitSet` has a `valueOf(byte[])` method. How do you want the bytes in the array to be interpreted?

Comment: Why when I write BitSet a = valueOf(test)， it appears no such function?

Comment: Because in that context, you are invoking `valueOf` as a `static` method of the current class the call appears in. You want to do `BitSet.valueOf(..)`.

Comment: On my computer, I still could not get BitSet q = BitSet.valueOf(test); run why?

Comment: Any time you have an error, post it if you don't understand it.

Comment: BitSet q = BitSet.valueOf(test); it says that The method valueOf(byte[]) is undefined for the type 
 BitSet , why?

Comment: it says that The method valueOf(byte[]) is undefined for the type BitSet ,

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your edit. That method was added in Java 7.

Comment: Is that because I download a free version of eclipse?

Comment: No, go to project properties, java compiler and set the compliance level.

Comment: need to download java 1.7....I will try..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer docs of BitSet , there is   `valueOf()` method

[`public static BitSet valueOf(byte[] bytes)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#valueOf%28byte%5B%5D%29)

> Returns a new bit set containing all the bits in the given byte array.

```
 BitSet a = BitSet.valueOf(test);
```

Comment: Why when I write BitSet a = valueOf(test)， it appears no such function?

Comment: @user3495562 Updated. You got wrong syntax. That is not the way to invoke a static method.

Comment: On my computer, I still could not get   BitSet q = BitSet.valueOf(test); run why?